# Could anyone tell me the basics about the differences of the browsers?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, google-chrome, safari

Why is it that when you work with different browsers, there's usually different results? Why is simple HTML/css being read differently by the traditional browsers (IE, Mozilla, Chrome and Safari)?

I'm sorry if this question doesn't belong here. I just thought you guys would be the best source of this type of information :)

Have a nice day!

Comment: Different software, written by different companies/contributors, (sometimes) interpreting a standard specification, but also pushing their own features. There's going to be differences...

Comment: I believe this is a valid (though broad) question. One might naively assume that because HTML is standardized, it should render the same in every display software (like, say PDF does). Why this is not the case is actually a fairly interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is seemingly a simply question but with a complex answer. Each company has built their browser on a different "layout engines". You may have heard of "Gecko" - The Mozzila Foundation's engine, similarly, Microsoft developed "Trident", Apple uses "WebKit" and Opera uses "Presto". Each interprets the specifications differently, and some just haven't caught up yet. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_browsers#Notable_layout_engines

I imagine that your question really is about how to tell the differences, and avoid/work around them.

I found that most of the basic elements work in all browsers. If you have any questions w3schools.com will show with each element how it's supported across browsers. Also, if you keep to 5px increments you can avoid *most* of the pixel-level browser differences.

There are horrible issues when styling emails. So be extra careful with them.

And finally, DO make sure to check across all browsers when designing. You'll be - unpleasantly - surprised if you don't.